# Simple HTML (or XML) to Android Native converter

Tags: java, android, html, xml, converters

I have a very simple data format that I want to frequently display that in my app.
The first approach is using native android components like TextView, ImageView and TableLayout.
But this approach makes me create a lot of different UIs. 
Second approach is to use WebView instead. This way I will lost speed. WebView is very powerful for such purposes but it kills UI responsiveness. 
The third way is to use a (very simple) HTML or XML and convert them to native android UI elements at runtime.

For example assume that I want to convert this simple html:

```
<div style="some_div_style">
    <p style="some_paragraph_style">A not-very-long-text comes here</p>
    <img src="..."/>
</div>
```

into this:

```
<LinearLayout style="@style/some_div_style">
    <TextView style="@style/some_paragraph_style" android:text="A not-very-long-text comes here"/>
    <ImageView android:src="..." .../>
</LinearLayout>
```

at runtime.

Do you know any library for doing such HTML (or XML) converter?

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but I'd suggest just biting the bullet and building the corresponding UIs natively... this will make the UIs feel much more at home on Android, not to mention allow your development process to add native-only features that might not be possible to capture in this format.

Comment: maybe try some XSLT but didn't sure it will pass transformed data to elements parser.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you (or anyone need this) looking for:

[squarede](https://github.com/anpham6/squared)

> Converts and optimizes pure HTML and SVG into the various standard
>   Android layouts in XML. Easiest to use and also most accurate with
>   support for CSS/SMIL animations. Compatible with Chrome and Safari.

And yes! I know that it is an old post.

Answer (score 0):

So if understand your question right you want a tool to create an app using HTML and other web technologies.

One that I can recommend is PhoneGap Build by Adobe, basically you upload your HTML and config file (Instructions in documentation) to the website and then it is converted into an app file. This can be used to create both Android and iOS (needs signing certificate) relatively easy.

This would not per se directly covert your HTML into android XML but would allow you to create an interface in HTML that can then be build and compiled into an app.

A link to PhoneGap Build: https://build.phonegap.com

There are other tools that use the same framework (Cordova) to achieve this but I have found this is the easiest and most user friendly way to do this.

---

Although this answer is late I hope it will eventually be of help to someone!

Feel free to comment any additional questions or queries and I will era happy to address them.